# How would I calculate overtime pay?

Tags: vba

I'm new to Visual Basics and I need some help.

I need to calculate the overtime pay into the gross pay.

Here is my whole code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Assigns integer and decimals'

    Dim intHoursWorked As Integer
    Dim decPayPerHour As Decimal
    Dim decGrossPay As Decimal
    Dim decTax As Decimal
    Dim decNetPay As Decimal

    'Conversions' 

    If IsNumeric(Me.HoursWorked.Text) Then
        intHoursWorked = Convert.ToInt32(Me.HoursWorked.Text)

        If IsNumeric(Me.txtPPH.Text) Then
            decPayPerHour = Convert.ToDecimal(Me.txtPPH.Text)
        End If
    End If

    'Hours worked + overtime' 

    If intHoursWorked > 48 Then
        MsgBox("You have exceeded your maximum hours")
        Me.HoursWorked.Text = ""
        Me.lblNetPay.Text = ""
        Me.lblGrossPay.Text = ""
        Me.lblTax.Text = ""
    ElseIf intHoursWorked < 23 Then
        MsgBox("You must enter at least 23 hours")
        ' Add time and a half for overtime
    ElseIf decGrossPay = decGrossPay + (decGrossPay - 40) * 0.5 Then
    End If

    'Pay per hour'

    If decPayPerHour < 14.25 Then
        MsgBox("You must enter a value above $14.25")
    ElseIf decPayPerHour > 100 Then
        MsgBox("You must enter a value lower than $100")
    Else
        If Me.radSingleRate.Checked = True Then
            decTax = 0.205D
        ElseIf Me.radFamilyRate.Checked = True Then
            decTax = 0.15D
        End If
    End If

    'Calculations for Gross, Tax, and Netpay'

    decGrossPay = intHoursWorked * decPayPerHour
    decTax = intHoursWorked * decPayPerHour * decTax
    decNetPay = decGrossPay - decTax

    Me.lblGrossPay.Text = decGrossPay.ToString("C")
    Me.lblNetPay.Text = decNetPay.ToString("C")
    Me.lblTax.Text = decTax.ToString("C")
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.txtName.Focus()
    Me.radSingleRate.Checked = True
    Me.lblTax.Text = ""
    Me.lblGrossPay.Text = ""
    Me.lblNetPay.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ' Clears all inputs ' 

    Me.txtName.Text = ""
    Me.HoursWorked.Text = ""
    Me.txtPPH.Text = ""
    Me.lblGrossPay.Text = ""
    Me.lblTax.Text = ""
    Me.lblNetPay.Text = ""
    Me.radSingleRate.Checked = True
    Me.radFamilyRate.Checked = False
    Me.txtName.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    ' Closes Application '

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

I can't figure out what code I should be typing into my code to have it calculate the gross pay. The overtime should be automatically calculated by the program if a number over 40 hours worked is inputted by the user. Overtime is time and a half.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to have posted a lot of code which is not relevant to your actual question. You might get a better response if you make an effort to trim your code down to a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `decGrossPay = decGrossPay + (decGrossPay - 40) * 0.5` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like this?

```
Select Case intHoursWorked

    Case Is > 48
    
        MsgBox ("You have exceeded your maximum hours")

    Case Is < 23
    
        MsgBox ("You must enter at least 23 hours")
            
    Case 40 To 48

        decGrossPay = decGrossPay * 5
        
    Case Else
    
        'Add code for any other scenarios if required.

End With
```

Edit, not really sure how you are calculating the pay. Don't you need a figure for the regular hourly rate? If so, maybe something like this. Can't test because it's only partial code and just a guess.

```
Select Case intHoursWorked

    Case Is > 48
    
        MsgBox ("You have exceeded your maximum hours")

    Case Is < 23
    
        MsgBox ("You must enter at least 23 hours")
            
    Case 40 To 48

        decGrossPay = hourlyrate * 40  + ((intHoursWorked - 40) * (hourlyrate * 1.5))
        
    Case Else
    
        decGrossPay = hourlyrate * intHoursWorked

End With
```

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying when I posted this but the hourly rate is input by the user when trying to calculate.

Comment: I have also changed the post to have all my code.

Answer (score 0):

This part got problem as you did not consider the hours between 24 ~ 48:

```
ElseIf intHoursWorked < 23 Then
        MsgBox("You must enter at least 23 hours")
        ' Add time and a half for overtime
    ElseIf decGrossPay = decGrossPay + (decGrossPay - 40) * 0.5 Then
    End If
```

Should it work if you amend the code as following, so that if the worker work more than 24 but less than 40 hours, they only get basic hours, when they work more than 40 hours, they will get basic + OT, although I did not go through the remaining part and i am consider the decGrossPay is total hours to be paid:

```
  ElseIf intHoursWorked < 23 Then
            MsgBox("You must enter at least 23 hours")
            ' Add time and a half for overtime
ElseIf intHoursWorked > 40 and intHoursWorked <= 48 Then
        decGrossPay = 40+ ((intHoursWorked - 40)  *0.5 )
else decGrossPay = 40
    End If
```

Comment: Kin, you must have posted as I was editing my post :)

Comment: Thanks for answering but I've used your code and the same thing is happening, overtime is not being calculated if anything over 41 hours worked is inputted. I've put the whole code above if you would like to try anything else (don't have to). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thank you for helping me! It works now. Thank you for providing some more code again.